# Similar content for same cards bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new at web design. My first project is to make a movie cinema website. I made the index.html where i have 20 cards with different movies. They are clickable and i want to show the description of the movie and the actors playing. My question is, do i have to make 20 html files and code each one of the movies to navigate in the description or is there any better way?

Comment: If you're gonna use just HTML, then yes. If you're gonna mix it with some sort of backend technology like PHP/NodeJS/JAVA (or anything) and a database, then no.

Comment: @SiddhartBhansali i would like to mix it with backend. Which would be the best option?

Comment: Of course the backend-frontend-db combo is the best and the most common one. But if you're just starting with web development, then you might wanna move slowly from one end to the other. HTML/CSS/JS then to some sort of frontend framework like ReactJS, then to a backend technology like NodeJS (or whatever you wanna learn), and same time you learn the DB.